# Clearing the field of a form with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

Sounds easy probably, but not for a beginner programmer :)

I have a simple 3 field form with a submit button and a clear button. This is for a homework assignment, and we have been tasked to get the "Clear Fields" button to work properly. Here are more specific instructions:

"Add the JavaScript code for an anonymous function that's stored in a variable named clear. The function should clear the text boxes by using the $ function to get a Textbox object for each text box and then setting the value property of the textbox to an empty string. Then, add a statement in the onload event handler that attaches the clear function to the click event of the Clear Entries button."

I was able to add the statement to the onload event handler:

```
window.onload = function () {
        $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;
        $("miles").focus();
        $("clear").onclick = clear;
    }
```

But it is the other part I am having problems with.

Add the JavaScript code for an anonymous function that's stored in a variable named clear:

```
var clear = function () {
        Object.Method   
        }
```

Here is my full code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Calculate MPG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mpg.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script>
        var $ = function (id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
        var calculateMpg = function () {
            var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value);

            var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);

            if (isNaN(miles)) {
                alert("Miles: This must be a numeric value.");}
                else if (miles <0) {
                    alert("Miles: This number must be greater than 0.");}
                else if (isNaN(gallons)) {
                    alert("Gallons: This must be a numeric value.");}
                else if (gallons <0) {
                    alert("Gallons: This number must be greater than 0.");}
            else {
                var mpg = miles / gallons;
                $("mpg").value = mpg.toFixed(1);
            }
        }
        var clear = function () {
            miles.Text = String.Empty
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;
            $("miles").focus();
            $("clear").onclick = clear;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Calculate Miles Per Gallon</h1>
        <label for="miles">Miles Driven:</label>
        <input type="text" id="miles"><br>
        <label for="gallons">Gallons of Gas Used:</label>
        <input type="text" id="gallons"><br>
        <label for="mpg">Miles Per Gallon</label>
        <input type="text" id="mpg" disabled><br>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate MPG"><br>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear Entries"><br>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code we were supplied with to work off of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculate MPG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mpg.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  
    <script>
        var $ = function (id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
        var calculateMpg = function () {
            var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value);
            var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value);

            if (isNaN(miles) || isNaN(gallons)) {
                alert("Both entries must be numeric");
            }
            else {
                var mpg = miles / gallons;
                $("mpg").value = mpg.toFixed(1);
            }
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;
            $("miles").focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Calculate Miles Per Gallon</h1>
        <label for="miles">Miles Driven:</label>
        <input type="text" id="miles"><br>
        <label for="gallons">Gallons of Gas Used:</label>
        <input type="text" id="gallons"><br>
        <label for="mpg">Miles Per Gallon</label>
        <input type="text" id="mpg" disabled><br>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate MPG"><br>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not use input type reset?

Comment: That's not the way to bind click event using jQuery: `$("calculate").onclick = ...`

Comment: your selectors don't have class `.` or id `#` stipulations

Comment: To be fair, I am new to this, and am not sure what that entails or if it meets the requirements of the assignment. While doing reset might be easier, I want to be deliberate with what the instructor has asked. Would reset accomplish this? I don't know truthfully.

Comment: Can you be more specific - remember this is a beginner :) Which selectors? Maybe an example?

Answer (score 0):

You've got several issues going on:

1. You're mixing Javascript and jQuery in ways that don't quite work.
   jQuery's methods and objects work differently than "pure"
   Javascript, so be mindful of that.
2. The `window.onload` doesn't work the way you've got it. To be
   consistent, do it the jQuery way with a `$(document).ready()` method
   instead.
3. You're missing the `#` indicator on your jQuery IDs. This is
   imperative or it won't find the ID of the elements you're calling.
4. It looks like you're mixing VB/C# code in with your javascript, such
   as the `String.Empty` call, etc. Those objects/methods work from the
   server and not in Javascript, so that's another issue (it's been a
   while since I've worked in C#, so double check me on that).

Here's my solution below. I tweaked a few things to help with what I think you're going for (such as clearing ALL fields with the "Clear" button instead of just the `miles` field).

**I understand you're a student, so don't make it a habit of coming here and trying to find people to do your homework for you.** You did provide an attempt at some code, and there were a number of issues in it, so I chose to rectify them for you and explain the reasons since there were so many. Others are not as generous, but I was a struggling student once, too, so I get it when you're banging your head against the wall. :-)

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

var clear = function () {
    miles.value = "";
    gallons.value = "";
    mpg.value = "";
}

var calculateMpg = function () {
    var miles = parseFloat($("#miles").val());
    var gallons = parseFloat($("#gallons").val());
    if (isNaN(miles)) {
        alert("Miles: This must be a numeric value.");
    }
    else if (miles <0) {
        alert("Miles: This number must be greater than 0.");
    }
    else if (isNaN(gallons)) {
        alert("Gallons: This must be a numeric value.");
    }
    else if (gallons <0) {
        alert("Gallons: This number must be greater than 0.");}
    else {
        var mpg = miles / gallons;
        $("#mpg").val(mpg.toFixed(1));
    }
}

$("#calculate").bind("click", calculateMpg);
$("#miles").focus();
$("#clear").bind("click", clear);

        });
```

Comment: Thank you - I will try this. In my defense though, most of this code was provided to me by the teacher, which is why I didn't want to alter it too much. Part of the homework was to add the validation (which I was able to do), and then to get the "Clear Fields" button to work - but we had to use the code we were supplied with. I will report back how it worked for me. And thanks again - I dont want people to do my homework, I genuinely want to learn!

Comment: So is your prof wanting you to provide a C# solution to the "clear" function?

Comment: Prof was not specific - I am going to paste the code we were supplied with to work off of up above so you can see the restrictions we had.

Comment: Update - by just leaving the code as I had it, and adding the:

    miles.value = "";
    gallons.value = "";
    mpg.value = "";

The code worked - it is clearing.